# Specifying a specific date value in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, date, pandas, datetime64

I have a dataframe `df`, with two columns, `GROUP_ID={A,B}` and `ACTION_DATE`. What I want to do is to replace the `ACTION_DATE` value to `03/31/2006`, if the `GROUP_ID`'s value is `B`. Data type of `ACTION_DATE` is `datetime64[ns]`.

So, I tried the following.

```
df[(df.GROUP_ID == 'B')].ACTION_DATE = '03/31/2006 0:00'
```

The above line runs with no errors, but the resulting dataframe remains unchanged.

Could someone point out what I am missing?

Comment: Can you post some sample data???

Comment: GROUP_ID ACTION_DATE
A 2005-05-30
A 2005-05-30
A 2005-05-30
B 2005-05-30
B 2005-05-30
B 2005-05-30

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df.GROUP_ID == 'B', 'ACTION_DATE'] = '03/31/2006 0:00'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion, and I got this error message --- AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'view'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
df['ACTION_DATE'][df['GROUP_ID'] == 'B'] = '03/31/2006 0:00'
```

At times placing the column upfront works...

Answer (score 0):

The following worked:

```
import pandas as pd
df[(df.GROUP_ID == 'B')].ACTION_DATE = pd.to_datetime('03/31/2006 0:00')
```